# Making sense of some bit magic in the Go standard library

Tags: colors, go, bit-manipulation, bitmapdata, rgba

so I've been sifting through some code in the Go standard library trying to make sense of their image and color packages but found some code I just can't make sense of.
from http://golang.org/src/pkg/image/color/color.go?s=794:834#L14

From my understanding it should convert 8bit pre-alpha-multiplied RGB values to 16 bit ones, saved in 32bit variables to stop them from overflowing when multiplying in image arthimetic.

What I can't make sense of are the lines like `r |= r << 8` as I understand it this is equivalent to `r = r*2^8+r` because `r << 8` inserts zeros to the right and they get or'ed with the old r.

For an input of r=255 this evaluates to 65535=2^16 - 1 which is as expected, but it doesn't make sense for the values in the middle, which don't really get mapped to something proportional in the bigger range.
For example 127 get's mapped to 32639 while I'd expect 32767 to represent 127.
What am I missing? I think it has something to do with the pre-alpha-multiplication...

```
 func (c RGBA) RGBA() (r, g, b, a uint32) {
    r = uint32(c.R)
    r |= r << 8
    g = uint32(c.G)
    g |= g << 8
    b = uint32(c.B)
    b |= b << 8
    a = uint32(c.A)
    a |= a << 8
    return
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No, what you're seeing actually makes sense.

Think of a single (red, for example) value. It dictates the amount of redness in the pixel and, as an 8-bit quantity, it's somewhere between 0 and 255. Thus you can represent all values of redness in the range.

If you just bitshifted that by eight bits (or multiplied by 256) to get a 16-bit colour value, you'd end up with a multiple of 256 somewhere between 0 and 255*256 (65280) inclusive.

While that scales the redness up relatively well, it doesn't distribute it properly across the full 16-bit range.

For example, 255 in the 8-bit range means maximum redness. Simply multiplying that by 256 doesn't give you the maximum amount of redness on the 16-bit scale, which would be 65535.

By multiplying by 256 and *then* adding the original (effectively multiplying by 257), it distributes correctly across the 0..65535 range.

It's the same as scaling up the single-digit integers `0..9` into the range `0..99`. Multiplying by ten is one way but a better way is to multiply by ten and add the original value (or multiply by eleven):

```
n     n*10     n*10+n
-     ----     ------
0        0          0
1       10         11
2       20         22
3       30         33
4       40         44
5       50         55
6       60         66
7       70         77
8       80         88
9       90         99
```

Comment: I understand that it's better then just shifting, but isn't it still wrong?
For example in the decimal case 5 get's mapped to 55 so it looses the property of being right in the middle.

Comment: @NiklasSchnelle, 5 is only in the middle if you consider the top value to be 10 (or 9.9999...). In actuality, the top value is 9 so 4.5 would be the "middle" value. Hence the "position" where 5 exists is 5/9, which is exactly the same place where 55 exists in the 0..99 range (55/99). Your problem seems to lie with the fact that you think the byte range is `[0,256)` (inclusive of zero but exclusive of 256, meaning up to 255.99...) whereas it is in fact `[0,255]` (inclusive at both ends).

Comment: In other words, the "middle" is the average of the upper and lower bound `(0+9)/2 = 4.5`. If you multiply 4.5 times 11, you get 49.5 which has the same property in the two-digit range: `(0+99)/2 = 49.5`.